# Can I draw rectangle with text in EditText dynamically?

Tags: android

Can I draw rectangle with text in EditText? The text in rectangle should be added dynamically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass EditText and create a custom view that draws rectangles around the text, but that is far from straightforward.